# Error in android emulator

Tags: ubuntu, android-emulator

I am creating new virtual device using ubuntu

```
gelelio@ubuntu:/media/Android/eclipse-linux/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools$ ./android
```

I have create new emulator but when i start that emulator it give me an error like:

```
SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get "SDL init failure" with user jenkins,
but not with user root.

Try to run as root,
 to verify if it's a user permission or user environment issue.

Comment: Thank user77115 , i don't know what is error but when i run this in fedora-15 it's work perfectly and then i copy the all the data to Ubuntu10 then it's working perfectly.    i think it's only happen when you are in only user not a root user.